# SafariにおけるJavaScriptエラー二つ

Tags: javascript, safari

お世話になってります。SafariにてJavaScriptで発生しているエラーについてご質問させてください。

１．   [Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'. Expected a ':' following the property name 'myJson'.
    （anonymous 関数)
と言う表示が発生します。
このエラーはJavaScriptで定義した関数
function get_calc_result()の中で発生しており

```
jsonText = "{";
for( i = 0, j = 1; i < adultDays.length; i++, j++ )
{
    var tgt = '"otona_stay' + j + '" : ' + adultDays[i] + ',';
    jsonText += tgt;
}

for( i = 0, j = 1; i < childDays.length; i++, j++ )
{
    var tgt = '"kodomo_stay' + j + '" : ' + childDays[i] + ',';
    jsonText += tgt;
}

jsonText += '"product_id"' + ':' + product_id + ',';
jsonText += '"madori"' + ':' + '"' + madori + '",';
jsonText += '"startDay"' + ':' + '"' + startDay + '",';
jsonText += '"endDay"' + ':' + '"' + endDay + '",';
jsonText += '"numAdult"' + ':' + numAdult + ',';
jsonText += '"numKids"' + ':' + numKids + ',';
jsonText += '"numFuton"' + ':' + numFuton + ',';
jsonText += '"numPet"' + ':' + numPet + ',';
jsonText += '"taxRate"' + ':' + taxRate + ',';
jsonText += '"taxrule"' + ':' + taxrule + ',';
jsonText += '"parking_use"' + ':' + parking_use + ',';
jsonText += '"parking_num"' + ':' + parking_num + ',';
jsonText += '"parking_fee"' + ':' + parking_fee + '}';

var myJson = $.parseJSON(jsonText);
```

の箇所で発生している様に思われます。

２．先に申し上げたfunction get_calc_result()ですが、
    
から呼び出しているのですが、ボタンをクリックすると
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: get_calc_result
と言うエラーが発生します。

FireFoxやChromeでは正常に動作しているのですが、Safariだけが動作しません。

解決法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示頂ければ幸いです。

どうぞ宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: parking_fee が空文字になる可能性がありますでしょうか？

`"parking_fee": }`

←こうなっている気がします。


質問の主旨からはズレますが、根本的なところで気になったのが、最後に parse して オブジェクト化するのであれば、さいしょから オブジェクトとして扱ったほうがスムーズかと感じました。

Comment: parking_feeが空文字になる可能性ですね。調べてみます！有難うございます。

最後にオブジェクト化するより、最初からオブジェクトとして扱う方がスムーズとのご指摘有難うございます。

恥ずかしながらJavaScriptは詳しくなく、最初からオブジェクトして扱う方法が判らなかったもので…お見苦しいコードで申し訳ありません。